# Has any philosopher ever gone a step beyond solipsism and argued that nothing exists?

Tags: epistemology, nihilism, solipsism

I've heard that an example of an absolute certainty, is that there is a reality.  i.e. that something exists.

I cannot imagine how one could argue that nothing exists.  I know that even solipsists would maintain that the mind exists.

Have any philosophers ever argued that nothing exists, i.e. that there is no reality, or would that just be a)plainly wrong and b)impossible to argue c)a logical contradiction as it'd have to deny there is a thing thinking out the question  d) something no philosopher has ever even attempted to argue?

Can a philosopher argue even for a 0.0001%  or an infinitesimally or incredibly small chance or any chance at all, that there is no reality?

Comment: I don't see how one could entertain anything like a rational belief that nothing exists at all. Asserting "Nothing exists" is self-contradictory and therefore false. Asserting "There is nothing" is self-contradictory. I also doubt that the brain would allow anyone to merely believe that nothing exists, except presumably possibly diseased brains. That being said, it is always possible for anyone to asserts nonsensical sentences, although even the act of asserting that nothing exists as if it meant *something* would be self-contradictory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Gorgias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gorgias) argued that nothing existed in a now lost work called "On Nature". There are two surviving paraphrasis of it, however. The one by Sextus Empiricus can be found [here](http://users.wfu.edu/zulick/300/gorgias/negative.html), if you're interested.

Answer (score 2):

The status of "nothing is" is very sensitive what the context of "is" is.

The radical skeptics like [Pyrrho](http://www.iep.utm.edu/pyrrho) would withhold assent to even the most trivial everyday things, it is always "it seems so" to them, never "it is so", so they would not utter "nothing is". On the other hand, this can be seen as even more radical than nihilism, denying the possibility of asserting existence of anything in the first place, and of denying it as well. The second most influential figure in Buddhism, Nagarjuna, the sage of emptiness, is perhaps most often accused of metaphysical nihilism. His writings are full of subtle dialectic arguments for how everything that the traditional metaphysics posits to be — things, elements, souls, world, nirvana, etc. — is not. But his nihilistic tetralemma is more along the lines of Pyrrho:

> "*We do not assert “empty.” We do not assert “nonempty.” We neither assert both nor neither. They are asserted only for the purpose of designation.*"

And as Garfield explains in [Madhyamaka is Not Nihilism](https://www.smith.edu/philosophy/docs/garfield_nihilism.pdf), modern scholars interpret Nagarjuna as contrasting two perspectives, conventional and ultimate:

> "*The ultimate perspective is that of a fully awakened being — a buddha — from which all things appear as empty of any intrinsic identity or essence, as
>   interdependent, and independent of their presentation by conceptual thought, or as described by social or linguistic conventions. While... we can’t say anything at all from the ultimate perspective in virtue of its transcendence of the discursive, there is quite a bit that we can say from the conventional perspective.*"

This is in tune with a wide current in modern philosophy called [anti-realism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-realism) (the term was coined by Dummett, but the viewpoint much predates him), which can also be interpreted as saying that everything the traditional metaphysics talks about, substances, attributes, minds, etc., is not. The difference is that there is no "ultimate perspective" either. What they reject  is not so much the "isness" itself as the classical idea that there is some "objective", perspective-independent, content that can be placed in front of "is". Kant reduced it to the transcendent "thing-in-itself" of which nothing can be said or thought. But as Wittgenstein put it in Philosophical Investigations "*a nothing will serve just as well as a something about which nothing can be said*". But rather than answering "nothing" to "what is?" anti-realists are more likely to say that the question is a pseudo-question loaded with metaphysical misconceptions.

There is a very close modern position of (quasi)realism, which redefines ontology in non-metaphysical terms, and thus escapes the necessity of outright anti-realism (Quine and Putnam are examples). Turner gives an interesting analysis of [Ontological Nihilism](http://www.marcsandersfoundation.org/wp-content/uploads/paper_Turner.pdf) from this perspective:

> "*Ontological Nihilism is the radical-sounding thesis that there is nothing at all. Almost every one believes that it is false. But this does not make it philosophically uninteresting: we can come to better understand a proposition by studying its opposite... Ontological Nihilism faces a dilemma: if it is to be viable, avoiding the ills of Quiet Nihilism, it must embrace a particularly holistic picture of reality with an attendant bloated ideology and brute entailments.*"

Comment: what about yogacara buddhism?

Comment: @MATHEMETICIAN I think Yogācāra and Madhyamaka are in opposition. Even the mediating syntheses do not go as far as Nagarjuna. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yogachara#Yog.C4.81c.C4.81ra_and_Madhyamaka

Answer (score -1):

I do.

In fact, I think it's pretty easy to imagine.  VR headsets are becoming more common these days.  If you put one on for a short time, it's pretty easy to realize it was an illusion.  If you wear them longer, or more frequently, you may get an odd sensation when you take it off, and you realize the boundaries and objects in your 'real' room are very different than what your eyes were telling you for the last stretch of time.

From there it is a pretty easy jump to imagine VR with high visual fidelity, and feedback for our other senses.  In fact, this is technology that already exists in its infancy for helping people with PTSD (the 'smells' are pretty rudimentary, just opening a scented bottle that smells like burning rubber or gunsmoke...but it works when you have that VR helmet on).

When you can imagine that nothing your senses are telling you is real, it is a short jump to realizing that your very consciousness may not be real either.

If there is a 'reality,' it is probably so far outside our current understanding of how the world and ourselves work that it would be unrecognizable to us in our current state.

Comment: What you are talking about is called idealism, and it is not the same thing as believing that nothing exists. What idealism claims is that the physical world does not exist, but that minds and ideas do exist. Look up Berkeley's "A New Theory of Vision" for an early proponent of this view. Kant was also an idealist, but Berkeley is a lot easier to read.